# What is a DMZ in the simplest of examples?

Tags: dmz

I am new to the world of networking and am having a hard time understanding what a DMZ is. I understand a DMZ is where you place publicly accessible servers such as Web servers, Mail servers, etc. What I am confused about is how a DMZ is setup. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

- You have a router that is connected to the Internet
- Behind is router is a switch (I am unsure as to whether you can have a firewall instead)
- Behind the switch are the web and mail servers
- There is then a firewall which has 2 network interfaces one of which is connected to the switch
- The second interface is then connected to an internal switch
- Behind the internal switch are the LAN hosts such as PCs, Laptops, Printers, etc.

**EDIT**

Is it possible for a DMZ to be setup in the following manner as well?

- You have a router that is connected to the Internet
- Behind the router is a a firewall with 2 network interfaces one of which is connected to the router
- Behind the firewall is a switch with which the second interface is connected with
- Behind the switch are the publicly accessible web and mail servers
- There is a secondary firewall with 2 network interface cards one of which is connected to the switch
- The second network interface card is then connected to a internal switch
- Behind the internal switch are the LAN hosts such as PCs, Laptops, Printers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a router/firewall with three interfaces: internet, internal, and DMZ.  On the internet side you have your uplink.  On the internal side, you have your non-internet facing or private hosts.  On the DMZ interface you connect any hosts that are accessible directly from the internet.

http://www.shorewall.net/three-interface.htm

Comment: Having read a number of articles, they suggest that it is not advisable to use a router/firewall that has 3 interfaces. The reason being is if the router/firewall is compromised, the intruder would also have access to the internal network.

Comment: That's certainly a tradeoff.  The alternative, which is more complex, is to have two separate firewall/router devices in a "sandwich" configuration.  For the purposes of your initial question, and focusing on the "simplest of examples" my answer stands.

Comment: Thanks. Would the `sandwich` configuration be what I added in my `EDIT`?

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: Sweet. So my understanding is on the right track.